# Is there any way to better index geographical queries with postgis for query performance

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a fairly large (2 million records) table called `places`. I use two `numeric(9,6)` columns called `latitude` and `longitude` for storing geographic locations.

Now often I need to ask: "how many places are located within x kilometers (radius) from a point.

I do this with a query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS active_count 
FROM de."places" 
WHERE "places"."state" = 'active'
AND (extensions.ST_DWithin( extensions.ST_GeographyFromText( 'SRID=4326;POINT(' || places.longitude || ' ' || places.latitude || ')' ), extensions.ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(9.157190 48.808670)'), 15000 ))
```

My index looks like:

```
CREATE INDEX index_places_location
    ON de.places USING gist
    (extensions.st_geographyfromtext(((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || longitude) || ' '::text) || latitude) || ')'::text))
    TABLESPACE pg_default    WHERE state::text = 'active'::text
;
```

I have very beefy hardware (64 cores, 192GB ram, 8x Enterprice SSD in HW raid array etc.)
Now if I do an explain, I get something like:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=512320.91..512320.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1677.327..1677.327 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=512320.28..512320.89 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=1675.946..1732.657 rows=7 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 6"
"        Workers Launched: 6"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=511320.28..511320.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1655.383..1655.384 rows=1 loops=7)"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on places  (cost=125298.79..511310.07 rows=4085 width=0) (actual time=1506.195..1655.008 rows=3781 loops=7)"
"                    Recheck Cond: ((extensions.st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)) OPERATOR(extensions.&&) '0101000020E610000038842A357B502240CFA0A17F82674840'::extensions.geography) AND ((state)::text = 'active'::text))"
"                    Filter: (('0101000020E610000038842A357B502240CFA0A17F82674840'::extensions.geography OPERATOR(extensions.&&) extensions._st_expand(extensions.st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '15000'::double precision)) AND extensions._st_dwithin(extensions.st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '0101000020E610000038842A357B502240CFA0A17F82674840'::extensions.geography, '15000'::double precision, true))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1380"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=12774"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_places_location  (cost=0.00..125292.67 rows=367634 width=0) (actual time=1501.179..1501.179 rows=89886 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (extensions.st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)) OPERATOR(extensions.&&) '0101000020E610000038842A357B502240CFA0A17F82674840'::extensions.geography)"
"Planning Time: 0.786 ms"
"Execution Time: 1732.762 ms"
```

I don't know about you, but I somehow hoped for something quite a bit faster. Now am I overlooking some super smart PostGIS indexing functionality I should be using for this instead of what I'm doing atm?

PS: Postgresql 11 and Postgis 2.5

**update**

```
SET enable_bitmapscan = off;
explain (analyze, buffers) SELECT COUNT(*) AS active_count 
FROM de."places" WHERE "places"."state" = 'active' 
AND (extensions.ST_DWithin( extensions.ST_GeographyFromText( 'SRID=4326;POINT(' || places.longitude || ' ' || places.latitude || ')' ), extensions.ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(9.157190 48.808670)'), 15000 ))
```

output:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=642181.64..642181.65 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=354.662..354.662 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=96669 dirtied=2043"
"  ->  Index Scan using index_places_location on places  (cost=0.41..642120.37 rows=24509 width=0) (actual time=2.079..351.946 rows=26461 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (extensions.st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)) OPERATOR(extensions.&&) '0101000020E610000038842A357B502240CFA0A17F82674840'::extensions.geography)"
"        Filter: (('0101000020E610000038842A357B502240CFA0A17F82674840'::extensions.geography OPERATOR(extensions.&&) extensions._st_expand(extensions.st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '15000'::double precision)) AND extensions._st_dwithin(extensions.st_geographyfromtext((((('SRID=4326;POINT('::text || (longitude)::text) || ' '::text) || (latitude)::text) || ')'::text)), '0101000020E610000038842A357B502240CFA0A17F82674840'::extensions.geography, '15000'::double precision, true))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 9660"
"        Buffers: shared hit=96669 dirtied=2043"
"Planning Time: 1.149 ms"
"Execution Time: 354.732 ms"
```

That was faster, why?

Comment: Try `SET enable_bitmapscan = off;` and see if that makes the query faster. Could you post `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the original query and the execution without a bitmap index scan?

Comment: That was faster, why?

Comment: Perhaps caching. Can I see `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the original query too?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe and @jjanes There is for sure something with caching going on. The first time (after a long while) I run the queries it takes between 3 and 6 seconds, no matter if enable_bitmapscan is `on` or `off`. Now, if I run the query immediately after (altering the coordinates) it succeed in 50-300ms in both cases with bitmapscan on/off. What does this tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Your bitmap scan is a bit weird.  The index scan found 89886 rows, the filter removed 1380, but you are only left with 3781.  I have to conclude your table is woefully under vacuumed.  I'm not sure which of those number are reported across all parallel workers and which for just one, but I don't think that that could be large enough to explain the discrepancy.

Did you run both queries repeatedly in alternation to make sure the results are not just a fluke or due to caching effects?  (Also, please follow Laurenz's advice, and turn track_io_timing on first if possible)